# error: ORA-06502 - PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small when use user-defined function

Tags: oracle

I'm a newbie and i need some suggest to resolve my problem
I created a user-defined aggregate function such as:

```
create type nvarAggregate as object
(
storedAtt nvarchar2(300),
static function ODCIAggregateInitialize (sctx IN OUT nvarAggregate) return NUMBER,
member function ODCIAggregateIterate (self IN OUT nvarAggregate, value IN nvarchar2) return NUMBER,
member function ODCIAggregateTerminate (self IN nvarAggregate, returnValue OUT nvarchar2, flags IN number) return NUMBER,
member function ODCIAggregateMerge (self IN OUT nvarAggregate, ctx2 IN nvarAggregate) return NUMBER
);
/
*****************************
create or replace type body nvarAggregate
is
static function ODCIAggregateInitialize (sctx IN OUT nvarAggregate) return NUMBER
is
begin
sctx:=nvarAggregate(NULL);
return ODCIConst.Success;
end;
member function ODCIAggregateIterate (self IN OUT nvarAggregate, value IN nvarchar2) return NUMBER
is
begin
self.storedAtt:=self.storedAtt||trim(value)||'; ';
return ODCIConst.Success;
end;
member function ODCIAggregateTerminate (self IN nvarAggregate, returnValue OUT nvarchar2, flags IN number) return NUMBER
is
begin
if trim(self.storedAtt)<>';' then
returnValue:=substr(trim(self.storedAtt),0,length(trim(self.storedAtt))-1);
else
returnValue:=NULL;
end if;
return ODCIConst.Success;
end;
member function ODCIAggregateMerge (self IN OUT nvarAggregate, ctx2 IN nvarAggregate) return NUMBER
is
begin
self.storedAtt:=self.storedAtt||substr(trim(ctx2.storedAtt),0,length(trim(ctx2.storedAtt))-1)||'; ';
return ODCIConst.Success;
end;
end;
/
**************************************
create or replace function nvarAgg(value IN nvarchar2) return nvarchar2 parallel_enable aggregate using nvarAggregate;
/
```

Now, when i use nvarAgg function in sql statement

```
select id,nvarAgg(iforField) from testtable group by id
```

i get error messages from oracle:

```
ORA-06502 - PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
```

Do you have any solution for that?
Thanks alot

Comment: Well, do the concatenated values for any ID exceed 300 characters? (Or 300 bytes, depending on your default string semantics)

Comment: i tried with maximum size of nvarchar2 (32767), but i still got the same result.

Comment: Sounds like you just have too much data when aggregated. But a comment on shreesha's answer suggests it doesn't error with varchar2. So are you using character or byte semantics? (Not that it will matter if you're reaching 32k anyway, I suppose). And even if it works now future data may exceed it. CLOB may be the way to go. But also make sure you aren't aggregating more values than you expect - doesn't look like it from your sample query.

Comment: my field was nvarchar2 type and i define aggregate function to aggregate its value. Example i have values such as:

Comment: my field was nvarchar2 type and i define aggregate function to aggregate its value. Example i have values such as: 
id   information
1    a
1    b
2    e
2    f
3    d
and i want to result in select is:
id    aggregatefield
1     a,b
2     e,f
3     d
but because my filed was nvarchar2 type, wm_concat() function return unreadable field
do you have any suggest for this trouble

Answer (score 0):

your error says numeric or value error: character string buffer too small.It means you are trying to put value whose size is more than the size of buffer. I think the problem is in the line

```
storedAtt nvarchar2(300);
```

things you can try 
1)increase the size of storedAtt.

```
 ex:storedAtt nvarchar2(1000);
```

2)change the datatype to CLOB

```
ex:storedAtt CLOB
```

Comment: Changing data type is not a hit and trial thing you would like to do. It could have  detrimental affects to performance.

Comment: It is fine when it is under 4k since it store it locally like varchar2.

Comment: If it is less than 4000 characters(or bytes depending on the semantics), then there is no question of CLOB. Also, we are talking about PL/SQL here, so VARCHAR2 itself has 32767 limit, not 4000. 4000 is the limit in SQL. Also, from 12c onwards, you could increase the SQL limit to 32767. You should mention all this in your answer to make it complete, else those are just comments which @Alex has already mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses, i'll try with CLOB data type, but column in my table is nvarchar2, i can't change it because my databse is a existing database which was used for a application of my company. I tried use type varchar2 for storedAtt attribute, but when i selected, data was displayed with incorrect font, i couldn't read them. i'm so sorry because my english too bad.

Comment: try this `storedAtt nvarchar2(1000);`. i think you are storing other than english text.

Comment: to shreesha:
I tried to change storeAtt to nvarchar2(3000) or CLOB, but it also don't resolve that problem.
It seem the error occure at line 19 of type body: returnValue:=trim(self.storedAtt);
Do tou have any idea about this?
Thanks a lot!